# Jquery: Get index of dynamically added div within another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am adding divs within a container div. I want to show the index of the child div on the left. How can I do this?

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').append('<div class="section">' + $(this).index('.container') + ' B</div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div class="section">A</div>
  <div class="section">B</div>

</div>

<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `$(this).index('.container')`, in your handler `this` refers to the button which is not a member of the `.container` selector so it will return `-1`

So one solution is to add a new `div` then find its index, I think you want the index based on the div's with class `section`

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('<div />', {
    "class": 'section'
  }).appendTo('#container').html(function() {
    return $(this).index('.section') + ' B'
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div class="section">A</div>
  <div class="section">B</div>

</div>

<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

---

Or you can find the already existing number of elements with class `section` and use it as the index for the new elemnet

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').append('<div class="section">' + $('#container .section').length + ' B</div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">A</div>
  <div class="section">B</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are appending the element will have index one length than the total elements with class section.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmw8tmy8/)**

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
   index = $('#container > .section').length - 1
   $('#container').append('<div class="section">' +index  + ' B</div>');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).index('.container')` will try to find the index of clicked button in container object.  Which does not exists due to which it return `-1`.

You need to use length of number of elements in container as index value here:

```
 $('#container > .section').length;
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').append('<div class="section">' + $('#container > .section').length + ' B</div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div class="section">A</div>
  <div class="section">B</div>

</div>

<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the `length` of `children()` of the container, like so:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    var newDiv = '<div class="section">' + $container.children().length  + ' B</div>';

    $container.append(newDiv);
});
```